# Use Google Play Gift Card To Test In-App billing and purchases - is this possisble?

Tags: android

I would like to know if anyone has successfully tried to use Google Play Gift Card for actual in-app purchase testing. Is it possible? I want to make sure before I purchase a gift card?

- I cannot find any online article regarding this scenario.
- I know I can use credit card but my credit card is under investigation - identity thief issue if you are so curious. So don't push me to use credit card. :-)
- I want to test a full in-app cycle with transaction reversal after 14 days so don't suggest the static responses test. :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I've just tried it with a German gift card (15 Euro).